# Hex Editor With Writing to HDD's

Tags: hard-drive, editor

I was wondering if any of u guys know a good hex editor for writing to HDD's and reading ofcourse.

I've tried wxHexEditor, but it seems it doesn't have the ability to write new stuff to the HDD (with write acces enabled ofc). I just need a hex editor that can open full HDD's or partitions of HDD's from sata and/or USB that can read the data on it, but aswell beeing able to write new data to it.

Hope you'll can help me out here.

Thx<3

Answer (score 1):

I normally just use `dd` to copy the area of interest between the disk and a file, then open the file in `emacs` and use its `M-x hexl-mode`.

Comment: thanks for ur answer! However, At the moment I read some good stuff about wxHexEditor and it looks quite solid. Only thing is, I can't write to HDD.. says something like "File has some insertion/deletions. You cannot save this file-self (yet). Please use SaveAs." and I can't find much information about that. Looks like it doesnt support to write to HDD's or something. And DD is way to much trouble, as I do hundreds of HDD's per day.

Comment: @Nerotix, what?!  You plan on hex editing by hand hundreds of drives per day?  This does not make sense.  What are you *really* trying to do?

Comment: I'm overwriting HDD's as a part of a low level format style. But sometimes the writing program doesn't write the whole disk and forgets a few blocks and/or sector and I manually write it to the drive. This way I know for a fact its overwritten. Thus deleted all old data that was previously stored on it, as a security measure. And every drive gets overwritten atleast a couple of times so the data is impossible to retrieve. Atm I'm doing so in Windows and I really dislike that, doing it with WinHex atm, bleh!:P

Comment: @Nerotix, then you should stop using this broken "writing program".  Just run `dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sdX` to fill the whole drive with zeros.

Comment: I wish it was that easy.. I do 20 HDD's at the same time, pretty sure that wont be reliable at the same time with DD.. unless u can proof me otherwise ;)

Comment: @Nerotix, why *wouldn't* it be?

Comment: How would I write random stuff to 20 HDD's at the same time with DD?

Comment: @Nerotix, for dev in sda sdb sdc ; do dd if=/dev/urandom of=/dev/$dev & done.  It should be fairly obvious how to expand it from 3 to 20.

Comment: at the end u say "of=/dev/$dev" what does the "$dev" mean? It takes every mounted drive in the $dev? I'm not quite sure with what it does.

Comment: it means substitute in the dev variable, which is set by the for loop to each of the listed devices: sda, sdb, and sdc.

Comment: Ah you meant it like that, yeah I knew that xD However, the way ur saying is doing with with DD and following it with && which will do it 1 by 1 and do the next one when the one before is done. What I'm doing now is do 20 together at the same time. Or am I mistaking what you're saying?

Comment: @Nerotix, there is only one &, which means run that command in the background and proceed immediately to the next.

Comment: Ah I see.. so 1 x & means it will turn it on and move to next.. didnt know. Thanks. However, that will be a heck of a long command for 20 HDD's :P

Comment: @Nerotix, not really... you can use wild cards too... `for dev in /dev/sd[a-t] ; do dd if=/dev/urandom of=$dev & done`.